# How to use <Editor> inside a UITableViewCell in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Am new to Xamarin and am using Xamarin forms to build a cross platform app. I'm trying to find out how to use a Editor (Text area) inside a Table View cell. I tried to google, but could not find out any solution. Can you pls help me with the code snippet for the same.

I thought I can create a custom renderer for an EntryCell, and try to customize height and enable multi line, but am not able to find out the properties to use, to maniupulate height and multi line.

If there is any other good way, pls let me know. Thanks always!!

Comment: you should use a ViewCell to build your own cell layout, you can include an Editor control that way

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing a few concepts, UITableViewCell is not in Xamarin.Forms but Xamarin.iOS. In Xamarin.Forms you have the ListView which contains ViewCells.

What you are trying to do is a Custom ViewCell and use the Editor Control which by default allows multiline input.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Editor BackgroundColor="#a4eaff" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

More about the Editor Control [here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor/)

Comment: Am trying to something like EntryCell, which gives a label+Entry field. I want to create some custom cell similar to that, with Label + Editor. EntryCell is available in Xamarin Forms. We can use Tableview in Xamarin forms, and am using the same. Pls let me know if you need more details.